# picture taken with camera doesn't resize in uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My code

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR!" message:@"Device has no camera!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

and the delegate

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.userImage.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Well, thats pretty simple and basic. My problem is that after assigning my image to the UIImageView I have (which has a pinned/fixed width and height) instead of resizing itself to the size of the uiimageview it stretches throughout my whole view, working more as a background that an image placed where it should be. Again, the width and height of my uiimageview has been pinned. Can anybody help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contentMode` of your `UIImageView` should be `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, instead of `UIViewContentModeCenter` as it seems to be.

If you need to change the content mode on the fly, just add this line:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.userImage.image = chosenImage;

    // Add this line
    self.userImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Not sure. This could very well be the answer to the original problem.

Comment: Why do I get a votedown on my question? Is there anything wrong with it. Obviously I will delete the question, but thats not very "community"-like

Comment: No, your question seems perfectly fine and explained to me. Have you tried what I told you?

Comment: Yes, I should've saved my comment above another minute:) It works... but the reason I had the mode on "center" is because I have a standard "camera" picture, in case the user doesn't choose to take or select a picture. Using aspect fit kind of messes up the aesthetics of that. I will just try to work around that by checking if the image is set to the standard. Again, Im sadly leaning towards deleting because I got devoted...

Comment: Then change the content mode on the fly. See my updated answer.

Comment: A friendly person decided to remove his devote (all for the community:P). Thanks for your reply, I really just needed a quick slap making me realise I used center mode...... Thank yoU!

Comment: @spynet Hehe thanks for clearing that up, I didn't think you did though (I think its someone hunting my thread, because I have received some vote downs recently without logical explanation; but I don't want to be paranoid...:)) Take care!

Comment: Don't care about downvotes. There will always be people to judge your questions dumb. Just concentrate on learning and communicating what you know and pretty soon your reputation will start growing even with inevitable downvotes. Welcome to SO!